# Show bootstrap modal on server side validation

Tags: validation, dialog

I have a ASP.Net Core MVC web application. I have a standard razor view which has a list of items with a delete button. What I want to do is if they user deletes an item from the grid go to the server calling an action which validates the item selected. IF invalid I want to return to the view and show a bootstrap modal explaining why the delete cannot be carried out. I call the delete routine using Controller / Action tag helpers and pass the unique Id to a controller event.

So basically if my delete validation fails show a modal dialog with a message. Any help please?

Comment: You need to add code so we can actually help. From the sounds of it you just need to return an error from the request and display the with some sort of alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sorting this myself. Basically I set a viewbag property and give it a value of show. Then in my script section of my view I set the modal property to that viewbag.